# Issue with /etc/sudoers file but can't access root

Tags: linux, azure, terraform, jira, sudo

I'm trying to install Jira Service Management on a Linux VM on Azure using Terraform. The install of Jira seems to work fine and I am now working on trying to attach the cert for Jira to the Java Key Store.

The problem I'm running into is when I launch the VM, I can't seem to run any sudo commands. When I type 'sudo' I get this error:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 123 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 124 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 123
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I've tried to edit the sudoers file and the editor opens up blank and says I don't have permission. I've read that I need to try running 'pkexec nano /etc/sudoers' but then it prompts me for the root password to run as the super user. I created the VM with Terraform and never set a password so I have no idea what the root password is. I can't run visudo because it returns 'visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied'.

What can I do to gain sudo privileges? Is there something in Azure I need to do or is there somewhere in the Terraform code when provisioning the VM where this could affect sudo privileges and capabilities?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is identical issue you can try the below suggestion that might works for you.

**1.  Rename your current file**

```
 mv /etc/sudoers{,.bak}
```

**2. Create a new one vi /etc/sudoers with the following basic content:**

```
    /etc/sudoers                                                                              # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
rahul ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dockerd
```

[image]

**3 . Run visudo and add your custom stuff.**

You can also try the different  [***troubleshooting***](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209558/how-can-i-fix-broken-sudo-sudo-parse-error-in-etc-sudoers-near-line-23) solution if above doesn't works.

Comment: Thanks so much for the informative comment! Unfortunately when I try running the first command (mv /etc/sudoers{,.bak}), I get a 'mv: cannot move 'etc/sudoers' to '/etc/sudoers.bak': Permission denied'. I also get permission denied when running vi /etc/sudoers. I can't do anything in this VM lol